# Create socket connection in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, sockets, phonegap-plugins

I have to open a socket connection (NB not websocket).
I have tried to use this plugin: https://github.com/blocshop/sockets-for-cordova.
It works well in Android and iOS, but is not not supported for Windows Phone 10.

```
socket = new Socket();
socket.open(
  ipAddress,
  port,
  function () {
      // invoked after successful opening of socket
      console.log("connected");    
  },
  function (errorMessage) {
      // invoked after unsuccessful opening of socket      
      console.log(errorMessage);    
  });

socket.onData = function (data) {
  // invoked after new batch of data is received (typed array of bytes Uint8Array)
  var message = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(data);
  console.log("message ", message);      
}

socket.onClose = function (hasError) {
  console.log("close");  
}

socket.onError = function(errorMessage) {
  // invoked after error occurs during connection  
  console.log(errorMessage);  
};
```

**EDIT:** The question is: Does someone know how to create socket connection in Phonegap for the Windows platform? (Other plugins)

Comment: OK, and what is the question? sockets-for-cordova declares support for iOS, Android and WP8. It does not support WP10.

Comment: I've edited my question, thanks @ZabojCampula